# MVP RxJava2 - managing Network error

Tags: android, error-handling, mvp, rx-java2, android-mvp

I try to follow the MVP design pattern using RxJava2. I'm new with it.
As I'm requesting data from an API, in my Presenter I call my Model like that:

```
mModel.getDataFromAPI()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(data -> {
        // Do something with the data
    }, throwable -> {
        // A wild error appears!
        // TODO: Display a dialog
    });
```

When there is an error, I want to display a dialog with a message to the user.

So what I was thinking is to create a `displayErrorDialog(String message)` on the View. But the problem is: I call the API a bit everywhere in the app, so it means that ALL my views will have to implement the method!

The dialog needs to be displayed by the View:

- to follow the MVP design pattern
- because I need the current Context to display the dialog.

I'm looking for a better solution to not have to implement the same method each time I have a new view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a `BaseView` that implements `displayErrorDialog(String message)` and then all of your views would extend from `BaseView`.

If you are using `interfaces` you could do the same using a `BaseInterface` and then you would be able to call your base view methods from any presenter.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I was thinking about. I've started to implement a solution like that. Thx. If nobody has a better solution I'll validate your answer.